# Translating the set phrase 後は～～だけ

Tags: set-phrases

I'm taking a sentence from page 49-138 of Lake and Ura's *Learn to Read in Japanese*

> ブラジルに行く準備ができて後は飛行機に乗るだけです。

The first part of the sentence (ブラジルに行く準備ができて) and last part of the sentence (飛行機に乗るだけです) seem pretty straightforward, but I'm not sure where 後は fits in with those. If it's associated with the first part of the sentence, it seems like it could mean

> After the plans to go to Brazil are finished, there's nothing to do but get on the plane.

but if it's associated with the second half of the sentence, it might mean something more like:

> The plans to go Brazil have been finished; later there's nothing to do but get on a plane.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「ブラジルに行{い}く準備{じゅんび}ができて後{あと}は飛行機{ひこうき}に乗{の}るだけです。」

＝

> 「ブラジルに行く準備ができて、後は飛行機に乗るだけです。」

You seem to be concerned about whether 「後は」 is associated with the first part or the last part of the sentence.  It is both, actually.

IMHO, what is more important here is whether or not you are looking at the set phrase 「**あとは～～だけ（だ/です/である, etc.）**」.  So, **you can pretty much forget about "later" or "after"** here.

> 「**あとは～～だけ（だ/です/である, etc.）**」 = "all that is left to do is ~~"

Thus, the sentence means:

> "My preparations for going to Brazil are finished and/so all that is left to do is to get on the plane."